# Access Query Not Working With Form Fields

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a form with 9 fields that are used with a query. The challenge is that the query does not seem to be pulling info from the form and only returns 0 records even if I input no data in the fields (it should return all data in this case).

I need the query to find data LIKE what is input.

Here's my query in SQL:

```
SELECT tblTestBats.Model, tblTestBats.BatCode, tblTestBats.BoxNo, tblTestBats.ReceivedDate, tblTestBats.Blank, tblTestBats.Size, tblTestBats.Manufacturer, tblTestBats.Category, tblTestBats.Material, tblTestBats.Ring, tblTestBats.RingLoc, tblTestBats.ReqNo, tblTestBats.WSUNo, tblTestBats.Owner, tblTestBats.Status, tblTestBats.StatusDate
FROM tblTestBats
WHERE (((tblTestBats.Model) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFindBats]![txtModel] & "*") And ((tblTestBats.Blank) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFindBats]![txtBlank] & "*") And ((tblTestBats.Size) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFindBats]![txtSize] & "*") And ((tblTestBats.Category) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFindBats]![txtCategory] & "*") And ((tblTestBats.Material) Like [Forms]![frmFindBats]![cboMaterial]) And ((tblTestBats.ReqNo) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFindBats]![txtReqNo] & "*") And ((tblTestBats.WSUNo) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFindBats]![txtWSUNo] & "*") And ((tblTestBats.Owner) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFindBats]![txtOwner] & "*") And ((tblTestBats.Status) Like [Forms]![frmFindBats]![cboStatus]))
ORDER BY tblTestBats.Model, tblTestBats.BatCode;
```

I am perplexed.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is as if the query does not "see" the latest form data. It appears to be a refreshing issue.

Comment: I recreated the query but only added one field criteria at a time. After about three fields the query "remembered" data I input on the form even though I reset (cleared) the form and changed the data. Somehow it is "seeing" old form data. WTF. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this weird issue. Turns out it was my data...specifically NULL data. Two columns in my table had NULL values and so the query doesn't see records using LIKE "**". It only sees blanks or data. NULL values it does not see.

Bottom line...it was not a refresh issue with forms or the way I was referencing the controls. It was because my data had NULLS. Fixed that and now it works great!!